# Python Library for Excel without installation

Tags: python, excel

I want to create a Python script to do some simple Excel work, i.e reading data from Excel files.

I do not wish to convert the files to .csv files.

I am restricted from installing any libraries for Python on my machine.

Is there a way to get hold of an excel library for python which I do not have to install onto my machine?

Comment: thats a long shot, but you can always copy a library's code within your program. Very bad practice but might solve your problem

Comment: try with virtualenv, with that you can install any library you want http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: You can also just put the library in the same path of your code